# How to make a div cover all available vertical space AFTER it wrapped in a row directional flexbox layout?

Tags: css, flexbox

Please have a look at this example: https://codepen.io/attilakun/pen/OJRYrEW

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="container" class="small">
    <div id="column1">
      <button id="toggle">Toggle width</button>
      <div>column1</div>      
    </div>
    <div id="column2">
      column2
      <div>There should be no gap between column1 and column2 when column2 wraps into a new row. If that happens, column2 should also expand to the bottom of the 300px high container but not more.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html, body, #container {
  height: 300px;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  width: 600px;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}

#container.small {
  width: 450px;
}

#column1 {
  background-color: red;
  height: fit-content;
}

#column2 {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 450px;
}
```

JS

```
window.onload = function() {
  const button = document.getElementById("toggle");
  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
     document.getElementById("container").classList.toggle("small");
  });
};
```

My aim is to eliminate the gap in the bottom:

[image]

Constraints:

1. Pressing "Toggle width" expands the container which causes the red and green boxes to be placed next to each other horizontally, the green box filling up all the available horizontal space. This should be preserved.
2. Adding "height: 100%" to the green box's style is not acceptable because it would overflow the 300px tall container. It would also make the green box's child items think they have 300px vertical space available which might result in poor layouting. The solution should ensure that the computed height of the green box equals the container (300px) minus the red box (dynamic height).

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `height: 100%` and combine it with `overflow: hidden` on the container

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const button = document.getElementById("toggle");
  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
     document.getElementById("container").classList.toggle("small");
  });
};
```

```css
html, body, #container {
  height: 300px;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  width: 600px;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}

#container.small {
  width: 450px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#column1 {
  background-color: red;
  height: fit-content;
}

#column2 {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 450px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container" class="small">
    <div id="column1">
      <button id="toggle">Toggle width</button>
      <div>column1</div>      
    </div>
    <div id="column2">
      column2
      <div>There should be no gap between column1 and column2 when column2 wraps into a new row. If that happens, column2 should also expand to the bottom of the 300px high container but not more.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

EDIT: If you can accept a fixed height on the red column, then it's pretty easy to do it with just CSS:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const button = document.getElementById("toggle");
  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
     document.getElementById("container").classList.toggle("small");
  });
};
```

```css
html, body, #container {
  height: 300px;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  width: 600px;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}

#container.small {
  width: 450px;
}

#column1 {
  background-color: red;
  height: fit-content;
  height: 40px;
}

#column2 {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 450px;
  height: 300px;
}

#container.small #column2 {
  height: 260px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container" class="small">
    <div id="column1">
      <button id="toggle">Toggle width</button>
      <div>column1</div>      
    </div>
    <div id="column2">
      column2
      <div>There should be no gap between column1 and column2 when column2 wraps into a new row. If that happens, column2 should also expand to the bottom of the 300px high container but not more.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: In this solution the height of the green container becomes 300px (I checked this on Chrome's "Computed" tab). This is not really good, because the green container's children will think that they have 300px vertical space available which is incorrect. The computed height of the green box should be less than 300px.

Comment: I appreciate that this was not clearly stated in my original question, therefore now I've amended constraint 2.

Comment: what is the desired effect if the children get bigger than the available space?

Comment: I want to use the green box's computed height to resize a canvas inside it such that the canvas spans the green box's visible height but no more. If it goes beyond, then the bottom of the canvas will become cropped.

Comment: would it be ok to give a fixed height to the red column?

Comment: I wanted to avoid that, but I'm curious what you have in mind.

Comment: I edited the answer, you can see a snippet of what I had in mind. If that's not an option, and you want a fully dynamic solution, I would probably use javascript to compute the height

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware that you'd give a fixed height to the green box as well. That's something I'd definitely want to avoid :/

Comment: you can use `100%` when the container is big, and `calc(100% - 40px)` when it's small, but other than that, I'm not sure how to do it in just css